# Error axios.post con React y Djanro Restframework

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, djangorestframework, react-router-dom, react-axios

buenas tardes/noches quisiera si me pudieran ayudar o orientar, estoy haciendo un mini proyecto de almacenar archivos en AWS S3 en un bucket(*puedo hacerlo desde el Backend en la consola del admin*) desde el Frontend **React** y utilizando **Django Restframework**, utilizo las librerías: boto3, django-storages ,coreapi. corsheadres, en el Frontend: react-hook-form y react-router-doom: les dejo el codigo de los archivos jsx y js, es un formulario simple,

Archivo jsx:

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async data => {
    try {
      if (params.id) {
        await updateArchivo(params.id, data);
        toast.success("Archivo Actualizado", {
          position: "bottom-right"
        });
      } else {
        await createArchivo(data);
        toast.success("Archivo Creado", {
          position: "bottom-right"
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error en handleSubmit:", error, data);
    }
    navigate("/archivos");
  });

 

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
      <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        
        {errors.nombre && <span><b>Requiere un Nombre</b></span>}
        <Form.Control
          id="formarch1"
          type="text"
          {...register("nombre", { required: true })}
        />
        {errors.archivo && <span><b>Necesita seleccionar un Archivo</b></span>}
        <Form.Control
          id="formarch2"
          type="file"
          {...register("archivo", { touched: true })}
        />
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Guardar
        </Button>
        {params.id &&
          <Button
            onClick={async () => {
              const confirmacion = window.confirm("Desea Eliminarlo?");
              if (confirmacion) {
                await deleteArchivo(params.id);
                toast.error("Archivo Eliminado", {
                  position: "bottom-right"
                });
              }
              navigate("/archivos");
            }}
          >
            Borrar
          </Button>}
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
  );
```

Archivo js como api del frontend con axios:

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8000/inicio/api/v1";

const infoAPI = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL
});

/* Archivos */
export const getAllArchivos = () => {
  return infoAPI.get("archivos/");
};

export const getArchivo = (id) => {
  return infoAPI.get(`/archivos/${id}/`);
};

export const createArchivo = (formData) => {
  return infoAPI.post("archivos/", formData,{
    headers: {
      'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
    }
  });
};

export const deleteArchivo = (id) => {
  return infoAPI.delete(`/archivos/${id}/`);
};

export const updateArchivo = (id, archivo) => {
  return infoAPI.put(`/archivos/${id}`, archivo);
};

/* Datos */

export const getAllDatos = () => {
  return infoAPI.get("datos/");
};

export const getDato = () => {
  return infoAPI.get(`/datos/${id}/`);
};

export const createDato = (dato) => {
  return infoAPI.post("datos/", dato);
};

export const deleteDato = (id) => {
  return infoAPI.delete(`/datos/${id}/`);
};

export const updateDato = (id, dato) => {
  return infoAPI.put(`/datos/${id}`, dato);
};
```

Errores:
[image: Error 2]

[image: Error 1]
Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Y ¿cuál es el problema? Leo la pregunta y no veo algun erro en tu descripcion.

Comment: ups se me fue. dejé ss no se si se ven bien